# Reading raw audio files

Tags: c, audio

How do you

1. Read a 16 bit stereo raw audio file in binary mode
2. Convert it's values to integer for right and for left.
3. Save those integers back to a new 16 bit stereo raw audio file.

The final two files should be the same, with my code, they are not. Why?

My code:

```
char ergebnis[80];                                                  
sprintf(ergebnis,"%s.neu.raw",Datei);
FILE* ausgabe = fopen(ergebnis, "wb");
FILE* f = fopen(Datei, "rb");                    
if (f == NULL)
  return;
int i = -1;
int r1 = 0;
int r2 = 0;
int l1 = 0;
int l2 = 0;
int l = 0;
int r = 0;
while((getc(f))!=EOF)
{  
  i++;
  if (i == 0)
    r1 = (unsigned)fgetc(f);
  if (i == 1)
  {
    r2 = (unsigned)fgetc(f);
    r = r1 | r2 << 8;  
  }
  if (i == 2)
    l1 = (unsigned)fgetc(f);
  if (i == 3)
  {
    l2 = (unsigned)fgetc(f);
    l = l1 | l2 << 8;
    putc(r,ausgabe);
    putc(l,ausgabe);
    i = -1;
  }
}  
fclose(f);
fclose(ausgabe);
exit(-1);
```

EDIT: Solved it with

```
int wo = 0;
while(wo !=EOF)
{
  wo = getc(f);  
  i++;
  if (i == 0)
    r1 = (unsigned)wo;
  if (i == 1)
  {
    r2 = (unsigned)wo;
    r = (r2<<8)+r1; //r1 | r2 << 8;  
  }
  if (i == 2)
    l1 = (unsigned)wo;
  if (i == 3)
  {
    l2 = (unsigned)wo;
    l = (l2<<8)+l1; //l1 | l2 << 8;   
    putc((char) ( r       & 0xff),ausgabe);
    putc((char) ((r >> 8) & 0xff),ausgabe); 
    putc((char) ( l       & 0xff),ausgabe);
    putc((char) ((l >> 8) & 0xff),ausgabe);
    i = -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: What differences do you see?

Comment: Won't `putc` write a single `char`, discarding the upper component of your 16-bit value?

Comment: @simonc what would you write instead?

Comment: Try `fwrite` instead.  Or write out the data byte at a time using `putc` or `fputc`.  In either case, you'll have to decide which endianess you expect from your source file and want in your destination file.

Comment: @simonc I tried fwrite (r, sizeof(int), sizeof(r), ausgabe); but that gives me  warning: passing argument 1 of fwrite makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default].

Comment: You'd need to pass the address of `r` - `fwrite(&r, sizeof(int), sizeof(r), ausgabe);`.  Note that this will write `sizeof(int)` bytes in host endianess. This will be 4 or 8 bytes on many systems.  Your question suggested you might want an output file that was byte for byte identical to your source file.  You won't get that with this approach.

Comment: @simonc Just tell me what to use.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  How many bytes do you want to write out for `l` or `r`?

Comment: @simonc Please read my questions, starting with "How do you 1. Read..."

Comment: I did.  It sounds like you want to recreate exactly the file you started with.  This seems unlikely (why not just copy the entire file if that's all you require) and your code doesn't match this interpretation of the question.  If you'd like help, please make a bit more effort over your question.  I don't mind helping you but you have to do some work too!

Comment: @simonc I want to manipulate the integers to store new values. But to do that I need to see that the workflow file -> bytes -> integers -> bytes -> new file works. I tried several settings for nmemb and size, the best I achieved was stereo with a left channel and an empty right channel(when the original was L+R). Currently it looks like http://pastebin.com/w9tafuiL, which doesn't work but is at least using fwrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getc in the while will skip one character.

Also if you have 16bit per channel instead of

```
putc(r,ausgabe);
putc(l,ausgabe);
```

do

```
putc((char) ( r       & 0xff),ausgabe);
putc((char) ((r >> 8) & 0xff),ausgabe);
putc((char) ( l       & 0xff),ausgabe);
putc((char) ((l >> 8) & 0xff),ausgabe);
```

Possibly you want a different endianness then just swaplines 1 and 2 and lines 3 and 4

Comment: This is an original: http://i.imgur.com/xdpTMdk.jpg and this is what your code created out of it http://i.imgur.com/EdmSzJV.jpg Also the original is 663kb in size, the modified one 1,29MB

Comment: Btw. are you aware that the getc in the while statement will skip one character?

Comment: That's the solution. If you put this into your main reply, others will see.

Comment: Is your input file 16bit per channel or 16bit in total? If it's per channel then you  will need the double character output per channel, otherwise your bitshifting during the read in is wrong as you are accumulating two 8bit chars into one channel.